# An error occurred while parsing EntityName XMLHttpRequest Request

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to do http `GET` request for a MS flow  using XMLHttpRequest in java script but getting the above error. 
I know this is because of the url.Can anyone help me what is the exact issue  with my url.

```
var finalurl = "https://prod4-30.centralindia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/ed30ad9219a940fa8e5af317cf697e4c/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=/triggers/manual/run&sv=1.0&sig=ctQe3OAscgTfzDgji9gS_B43lvHEV4JP-hGdaxu46wg";

function DohttpRequest(greeting) {
  alert(greeting);
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open('GET', '" + finalurl + "', false);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  console.log(jsonResponse);
  alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

I am doing the GET request  in sharePoint using the custom action. The definition of the custom action with  CommandAction is as below

```
                UserCustomAction SPToDBAction = collUserCustomAction.Add();
                SPToDBAction.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";
                SPToDBAction.Sequence = 10001;
                SPToDBAction.Title = "SPToDBAction";
                string location = "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children\">";
                SPToDBAction.CommandUIExtension = @"<CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions>"
                      + location
                       + "<Button Id=\"InvokeAction.Button\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" Command=\"EditFormButtonCommand\" CommandType=\"General\" LabelText=\"Sync SP To DB\" Image32by32=\"data:image/png;base64,iVB= \" />"
                       + "</CommandUIDefinition>"
                       + "</CommandUIDefinitions>"
                       + "<CommandUIHandlers>"
                        //+ "<CommandUIHandler Command =\"EditFormButtonCommand\" CommandAction = \"javascript:alert('Custom List ECB custom Action')\" />"
                        + "<CommandUIHandler Command =\"EditFormButtonCommand\" CommandAction = \"javascript:DohttpRequest('Are you sure  to sync the Items from Sharepoint to Database'); function DohttpRequest(greeting){ alert(greeting); var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlHttp.open( 'GET', '" + finalurl + "', true );   xmlHttp.send( null ); var jsonResponse = JSON.parse( xmlHttp.responseText); console.log(jsonResponse);  alert( xmlHttp.responseText);}\" />"
                        + "</CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>";
                SPToDBAction.Update();
```

Comment: First, it doesn't look right to me when you specify port `443` in the URL, your host would be listening to `443`. Just use the URL without `443`.  Second the error doesn't suggest any problem with the URL, you have an error in parsing the response, (which could be because of the URL). Can you just do a `console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)` before `JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);`?

Comment: If i gave the function app(azure function) url it was working fine.  If i gave the flow url  i am getting the  error

Comment: Okay, can you update the question with the `console.log()` of `xmlHttp.responseText`?

Comment: You are doing a `JSON.parse()` for `responseText`, is it a valid JSON data?

Comment: yes. For  function app url everything is working fine.

Comment: I sorry, I am not sure if I can help you. I believe your data response data has illegal characters.. look for links like: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08cf7e24-a46d-4d8d-a286-2688c73b6e6b/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname?forum=winformsdesigner

Comment: ok Thank you for your time. Will update the question if i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest (async = false) is not recommended because the JavaScript will stop executing until the server response is ready. If the server is busy or slow, the application will hang or stop.

With asynchronous request you need to wait for server answer, for do that you need to work with XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange property, so in the end your function code will look like this...

```
function DohttpRequest(greeting) {
   alert(greeting);
   let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         console.log(jsonResponse);
         alert(this.responseText);
      }
   };

   xmlHttp.open('GET', '" + finalurl + "', true);
   xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Hope it helps...